# Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Cannot find Bicep. Please add Bicep to your PATH or install Bicep

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to deploy a VNET utilizing this guide from Microsoft Learn (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/quick-create-bicep?tabs=azure-powershell#prerequisites). I have the main.bicep file written, however when I go to deploy the file using

`New-AzResourceGroup -Name TestRG -Location eastus`

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName TestRG -TemplateFile main.bicep
```

I get an error that states:.

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Cannot find Bicep. Please add Bicep to your PATH or visit
https://aka.ms/bicep-install to install Bicep.
At line:1 char:1

- New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName TestRG -TemplateFile ...

Does anyone know what is going on. It would be appreciated. Thanks again. I have installed Bicep already.

Comment: Did you install Bicep? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/install . The MS article assumes you already have it

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Cannot find Bicep. Please add Bicep to your PATH or install Bicep:

***Need to check below:***

- Reverify that bicep has installed properly in your environment ( `Install-Module -Name Bicep`). And once you installed it properly, check whether it is there in your system path as error says `Please add Bicep to your PATH`.
- Check the version of the installed bicep and upgrade it to the [`latest releases`](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/releases) if required.
- Check that the `path` of bicep file passing along with the
  `-TemplateFile`argument is accurately given because incorrect path will create this kind of conflicts.
- Sometimes there is an issue with the `PowerShell` deployment command `New-AzresourceDeployment`. After checking the above, if still the issue persists, try deploying the resource with `AzCLI` command.
  `az deployment group create`.
- Check and upgrade the Az PowerShell modules as it might also relates to this kind of issues.

Check the current installed bicep version using `bicep --version` command.

[image]

[image]

- Upgrade bicep using `az bicep upgrade` command if required.

[image]